# Is the infinite product map $(∏_{i=1}^{∞}S_{i})×f$ topologically transitive

Tags: gn.general-topology, ds.dynamical-systems

Let $f:X→X$ be a map. We say that $f$ is topologically mixing if for every open subsets $U,V$ of $X$, there exists $N$ such that for every $n≥N$ the set $f^{n}(U)∩V$ is non-empty.

Let $S : X → X$ and $T : Y → Y$ be dynamical systems. Then the map $S × T$ is defined by:

$S × T : X × Y → X × Y$, $(S × T)(x, y) = (Sx, Ty)$.

We know that if $S$ and $T$ are topologically transitive and at least one of them is mixing
then $S × T$ is topologically transitive (https://www.merry.io/dynamical-systems-lecture-notes/2016/10/3/the-shift-map).

My **question** is: Consider an infinite family of mixing continuous maps $S_{i}:X_{i}→X_{i}$ along with a topologically transitive map $f:X\to X$. Here $X_{i}$ and $X$ are compact sets.

Is the infinite product map $(∏_{i=1}^{∞}S_{i})×f$ topologically transitive?

Comment: Are you assuming that all the spaces are compact Hausdorff an that the maps are continuous?

Comment: @YCor: Yes. I will add this in the question.

Comment: Congratilations! You asked a question number **100,000**.

Comment: @PiotrHajlasz: But this number is not a prime. My fovirate numbers are primes.

Comment: You say that it's true for a family of 1 element, and asking about infinite families. But what about a family of two mixing maps (i.e., if $f$ is topologically transitive and $S_1,S_2$ are topologically mixing, is $S_1\times S_2\times f$ topologically transitive?)

Comment: @YCor: If you have a conterexample, then we are done

Comment: Is "topologically mixing" the same as "topologically transitive"?

Comment: @LSpice: No, mixing imply transitive.

Comment: @LSpice of course not, topologically transitive is much weaker. Irrational rotation of the circle...

Comment: I just ask because the question defines "topologically mixing", but then only asks questions about "topologically transitive".  I'm afraid I don't know the definition of the latter term, so, while I certainly believe @YCor's (counter)example, I can't check it myself.

Comment: Actually I'm sure of the definition of "topologically transitive" only when $f$ is a self-homeomorphism. Namely it means that for any two nonempty open subsets $U,V$ there exists $n\in\mathbf{Z}$ such that $f^n(U)\cap V$ is nonempty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\mathcal{X} = (\prod_{i=1}^\infty X_i ) \times X$ is endowed with the product topology, then to show that $F = (\prod_{i=1}^N S_i) \times f$ is topologically transitive (that is, given any pair of open subsets $U, V \subset \mathcal{X}$, there exists $n\in \mathbf{N}$ such that $F^n(U) \cap V \ne \emptyset$), it suffices to consider open subsets of the form 
$$U = \left(\prod_{i \le N} U_i \times \prod_{i > N} X_i\right) \times U'$$
$$V = \left(\prod_{i \le N} V_i \times \prod_{i > N} X_i\right) \times V'$$
 where $U_i$ and $V_i$ (resp. $U'$ and $V'$) are open subsets of $X_i$ (resp. $X$). As $(\prod_{i=1}^N S_i) \times f$ is topologically transitive (which can be proven by induction using the result you cite in the question since every $S_i$ is topologically mixing and $f$ is topologically transitive), it follows that $F^n(U) \cap V \ne \emptyset$ for some $n \in \mathbf{N}$.

Comment: Sorry for the late comment: this question seems to be a duplicate of one on MSE https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3108947/is-the-infinite-product-map-%e2%88%8f-i-1%e2%88%9es-i%c3%97f-topologically-transitive which has not been answered. Since you have a MSE account, perhaps you could flag the question on MSE for closure there as a duplicate of a question here?